# Can't setup port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm trying to setup port forwarding for my new game, so I can test it online.
*The game works well on lan when I use the local ip of the server.*

Here's what ipconfig says:

[image]

And here is how I setup the rule on the router:

[image]

I've looked at several tutorials, but none seem to explain what I might be doing wrong.
Maybe the subnet mask is bad?

Comment: What make and model of router is that you're using?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I made an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router's web admin UI screenshot looks a filtering/firewalling rule, for blocking traffic, not forwarding it. It doesn't look like a port forwarding / port mapping rule. You're probably in the wrong part of the UI. Look for something like "Port Forwarding" or "Port Mapping".